# Checking if a class has been instantiated in iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to check to see if a class has been instantiated in iOS.  If it has been instantiated then I want to release it.

something like

```
for (UIView* views in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([views isKindOfClass:[CCGLView class]])
            [views removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

For that's when I already know the it's a some sort UIViews, but how do I check for other classes?

Comment: Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: You don't need to check.  You can message nil in ObjC.

Comment: I looking for example code.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that you want to find out if an instance of class XYZ exists or not, or find all such instances.  AFAIK, there's no way to do this (in the general case) unless you keep track of the instances yourself (for which there are several possible techniques).

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to check to see if a class has been instantiated in iOS.

You don't need to.  Objective-C allows you to message nil without any adverse side effects.  Besides, subviews are not allowed to be nil, because they are added to an internal NSMutableArray, which, in turn, doesn't allow nil pointers to be added to itself.

> For that's when I already know the it's a some sort UIViews, but how do I check for other classes?

If you're looking to release every UIView (and related subclasses), you don't need to be as specific in your comparison, seeing as the base class (UIView) is the one that declares removeFromSuperview, which in turn, solves the deallocation portion of your question.  When a view is removed from it's superview, it's reference count is decreases by one.

Now that I have a little more context, what you're asking for is trivial.  If you're using ARC, this snippet here will find all objects of type `CustomClass`, then set them to nil.

```
for (NSObject *object in self.someCollection) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[CustomClass class]])
        object = nil;
}
```

If you're using MRC (and if you are, what the heck is wrong with you?), then you should, in fact, check for it being an active instance.

```
for (NSObject *object in self.someCollection) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[CustomClass class]] && object != nil) {
        [object release];
    }
}
```

Comment: for example, if I have MyClass got instantiated? How does Message nil would check for this? I am not too clear.  Give one or two lines of codes for clarification.

Comment: No, you're thinking too hard about this.  You don't need to check if an object is nil because you can message nil!  If you wanted to send nil removeFromSuperview, you could.

Comment: No, MyClass is not a View class it's some kind of class. Cannot removeFromSuperview.

Comment: Then do what you did before, check for a class, then set the pointer to nil (under arc), or call release.

Comment: OK, I want to know what's self.someCollection?  That someCollection must be category of class like self.view.suviews.  Can I say self.MyClass?

Comment: No.  Do you know what a collection is?  Perhaps you need to read a little more into what ObjC is, and how it works.